# Where can I find the translated manuscript of Abel?

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request, abstract-algebra, translations

I am looking for the translated manuscript of Abel where he proved the unsolvability of the quintic. Can anyone give me a pointer? I tried Google, but nothing came up.

Comment: I found it (scanned) [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0001&DMDID=dmdlog12), and did take a peek at it (I do read German). Filed under "read when I have some free time" though...

Comment: Translated to what language? :-)

Comment: Sorry. Translated to english. @AlexandreEremenko

Comment: Note that Abel wrote two versions of this proof, a very brief one in 1824 and a more expanded one in 1826.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Peter Pesic's popular math book [Abel's Proof: An Essay on the Sources and Meaning of Mathematical Unsolvability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262661829) contains the author's own translation of Abel's 1824 paper as an appendix. He also has some annotated notes which make understanding the exposition easier.

Answer (score 6):

I have doubts that it was translated into English. French and German works often go untranslated because it is assumed that most English speaking mathematicians can make out enough from the original. The original publication of Abel's collected works was in French. MAA hails old [German translation](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-works-of-abel-and-galois) without mentioning anything about English one, and promotes English translation of [Abel's elliptic functions](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/abel-on-elliptic-integrals-a-translation) paper, but not the quintic one.

I took pdf of the [French manuscript](http://www.abelprize.no/c54178/binfil/download.php?tid=53608), put it through Adobe Acrobat's OCR and saved it as a Word document, then translated that using Google Tranlate [translator toolkit](https://translate.google.com/toolkit). The [result](https://translate.google.com/toolkit/workbench?did=002oujh00rvcclugwvls&hl=en) is messy but looking at it next to the French text and formulas I can understand most of it.

Comment: Google translate, or any automatic translation that exists cannot be used to translate mathematics: you always obtain nonsense.

Comment: We should have a translated copy, don't you think guys, I mean most people doesn't understand french or german anyway.